# how [Authorize(Policy = "PolicyName")] works in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net

can someone tell me how [Authorize(Policy = "PolicyName")] works, when the user is not logged in why policy runs? for example if i return 'true' from .RequireAssertion method's delegate, action or controller is accessible even user is anonymous user?

```
[Authorize]
[Authorize(Policy = "TestAccess")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
{
   return Json("Test Actioned Reached");
}
```

why [Authorize] attribute is nacessary here? if [Authorize(Policy = "TestAccess")] means that - action/controller will be reached when user is not anonymous user AND this policy is passed?

if i write:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "TestAccess")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
{
    return Json("Test Actioned Reached");
}
```

and policy look like that:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
options.AddPolicy("TestAccess", policy => policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
   {
       return true;  // For Testing only

   }));
});
```

Test() action will be reached even user is anonymous user. what this is happening? Sorry for my bad english. Thank you.

Comment: can you put code snippet, you have tried till now? then SO can help you in better ways.

Comment: i added some information about question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out below code

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options => {
                    options.AddPolicy("TestAccess", policy => policy.RequireAssertion(context => context.User.HasClaim("your claim type ","your claim value")));
                });
```

---

your code simply adds simply true in Requirements Pipeline

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
options.AddPolicy("TestAccess", policy => policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
   {
       return true;  // For Testing only

   }));
});
```

above code add true in the pipeline of the handler and true satisfy all condition including an anonymous user also.

for more detail kindly have a look at the method src code

```
public AuthorizationPolicyBuilder RequireAssertion(Func<AuthorizationHandlerContext, bool> handler)
        {
            if (handler == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(handler));
            }

            Requirements.Add(new AssertionRequirement(handler));
            return this;
        }
```

[AuthorizationPolicyBuilder.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/AuthorizationPolicyBuilder.cs#L211)

Comment: in this scenario [Authorize(Policy = "TestAccess")] public async Task<IActionResult> Test() { return Json("Test Actioned Reached"); } when custom RequirementHandler will executed for this policy, it is guarantee that user is logged in user and not anonymous user? or we need extra check in handler method?

Comment: when RequirementHandler is executed, you can check claim of the user and verify it .

Answer (score 0):

add

```
policy.RequireAthenticatedUser();
```